# The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext' in snackbar

Tags: flutter, dart, crash, toast, snackbar

im facing the error in snackbar context im not able to do resolve this i applied path library, dart.js, this.context but cant resolve the error
ScaffoldMessenger.of(**context**).showSnackBar
show red snake at context

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Please check this link. You can also use Globalkey for scaffold. https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger